# How do I change rotation direction of single phase fan motor?

Tags: motor, single-phase

I have a single phase AC motor.  I found it from Photocopy machine.  That motor same to Fan motor.  It has a capacitor to make phase angle.  I don't know what is the correct name of my motor.

Can I change rotation direction of that motor?

**edit:**
This is the photo of my motor.  [image]

Comment: Maybe. It sounds like an induction motor. Photo? Part number? You can see it. We can not.

Comment: Sounds like a split phase or capacitor run motor.

Comment: As I know It make a phase angle between current and voltage using It's capacitor.Lot of table fans,small water pumps has this type of motor.

Comment: @KalleMP yes..its a split phase induction motor as describe in this link
http://www.electrical4u.com/types-of-single-phase-induction-motor/

Comment: Can you post a photo of the motor's nameplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to internal connections between the coils, you can reverse the motor by reversing the connection of one coil with respect to the other one.

[image]

Comment: This looks good.  Sometimes if the motor is made to be reversible then both windings are the same rating and you can move the capacitor to the other winding.  If it is a consumer motor that should only be used in one direction then the capacitor connected winding may be lower rating and you will have to follow the answer above to change the phasing.

Comment: This method is working properly.I change capacitor winding direction.It was a good way.
But I cant agree with @KalleMP. Winding has different resistance.

Comment: It is true that the windings are sometimes identical, but it is not surprising that a fan motor from a copy machine would not be that kind of motor.

Comment: @NSiri My comment was exactly to warn you that the windings may be different if the motor was not intended for simple reversal. The linked image shows the simple connections required for a motor designed for reversing. http://www.wimb.net/sec_slosyn/img0/singlephaseconn.gif

Comment: If the windings are not identical, then it is quite probable that the motor won't have equivalent torque in the "opposite" direction than it was originally designed for.